# Which artificial neural network can mimic biological neurons the most?

Tags: artificial-neuron, biology, neuroscience

On the Wikipedia page we can read the basic structure of an artificial neuron (a model of biological neurons) which consist:

- Dendrites - acts as the input vector,
- Soma - acts as the summation function,
- Axon - gets its signal from the summation behavior which occurs inside the soma.

I've checked [deep learning Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning), but I couldn't find any references to dendrites, soma or axons.

Which type of artificial neural network implements or can mimic such a model most closely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only a small portion of the habituation, sensitization, and classical conditioning behavior of neurons has been primitively simulated in ANN systems. Simulation of actin cytoskeletal machinery<sup>1</sup> and other agents of neural plasticity, central to learning new domains, is in its beginnings<sup>2</sup>.  As of this writing, the complexity of neuron activation dwarfs the models being used in working commercial ANN systems, but the research continues along multiple fronts.

- The neuroscience of learning<sup>3</sup>,
- Parallel hardware approaches that better support ANN simulation accuracy<sup>4, 5</sup>, and
- Dynamic frameworks<sup>6</sup>

This list and the examples referenced in the superscripts, with links below, represent a tiny sample of the information available and the work in progress.

**References**

[1] [Molecular Cell Biology. 4th edition.; Lodish H, Berk A, Zipursky SL, et al.; New York: W. H. Freeman; 2000.; Section 18.1 The Actin Cytoskeleton](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21493/)

[2] [NEURON Software; Yale U](http://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/)

[3] [Molecular Cell Biology. 4th edition.; Lodish H, Berk A, Zipursky SL, et al.; New York: W. H. Freeman; 2000.; Section 21.7 Learning and Memory](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21648/)

[4] [Artificial Neural Networks on Massively Parallel Computer Hardware; Udo Seiffert; University of Magdeburg, Germany](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231204000682)

[5] [NeuroGrid; Stanford U](https://web.stanford.edu/group/brainsinsilicon/neurogrid.html)

[6] [Explanation of Dynamic Computational Graph frameworks](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/3803/2444)

Answer (score 2):

Most artificial neurons model biological neurons but in a very simplistic way. Nowadays, the main aim is to achieve better performance at prediction tasks. However, there is a body of literature in neuroscience that looks at [computational models of neurons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Models_of_neural_computation). Neurons are complicated cells and our understanding of neurons is still not complete.

Answer (score 2):

ANNs approximate biological neuronal networks.  The approximation began with extreme simplicity in the early perceptron design.  [Spiking networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiking_neural_network) are examples of more accurate approximations.  More accurate still, are complex simulations of neuron behavior that therefore necessitate significant computing resources.

If you are interested in a mathematical overview on analysis of biological neuron models I can recommend [Dynamical Systems in Neuroscience](https://www.izhikevich.org/publications/dsn.pdf) by [Eugene Izhikevich](https://www.izhikevich.org/).

Answer (score 0):

A computational model that attempts to closely mimic the human neural networks is Numenta's [hierarchical temporal memory](https://numenta.org/hierarchical-temporal-memory/) (which has not yet received much attention from  the machine learning community). In their models, they explicitly model and implement dendrites and other biological concepts.